# Buildozer build reinstalling everything and taking too long

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I'm building a simple app with kivy and builozer, I have made the first apk file already, but every time I make a litle change to my app and run `buildozer -v android debug` again, It takes the same amout of time as the first time I did it, about 2 hours and I get this lines:

```
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 31
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (31)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 31 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/iker/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b
[INFO]:    Found NDK version 25b
[INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
```

I have the latest version of buildozer and all libs required. How can I solve this?